# How to overlap a darker layout over current layout during content loading?

Tags: android, xml, layout, progress-bar, overlap

i created an activity that include an AsyncTask to fetch some data from internet. I add a progressbar to the layout so users can't interact with edittext till up the data loading is completed.
During content loading i would make the current layout darker, so users understand that the layout it is not active during loading.
Is it possible to add a darker layout that covers the current one and that includes the progressbar widget?

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mylogo"
            android:src="@drawable/myapp_logo" />    

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMethod"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/method"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textSpinner"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMethod2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/method2"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editMethod2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textMethod2"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textTotal"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_button_event"
            android:onClick="send"
            android:text="@string/send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put a full screen view with darker background and visibility=gone. when your app is loading you change to visibility=true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/darkerView"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#60000000"
              android:visibility="gone"
        />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mylogo"
            android:src="@drawable/myapp_logo" />    

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMethod"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/method"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textSpinner"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMethod2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/method2"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editMethod2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textMethod2"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textTotal"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_button_event"
            android:onClick="send"
            android:text="@string/send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure android.app.ProgressDialog is designed for exactly this.  I mostly use indeterminate mode (no display of progress, just spinner) but its not really complicated to setup.

```
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(message);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

then from your async task, you can

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    //maintain a reference to your activity
    ((MyActivity)activity).updateProgressDialog(value);
}
```

where `updateProgressDialog(int value)` is in said MyActivity. Something like

```
public void updateProgressDialog(int value){
    if (mProgressDialog!=null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(value);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you're set on not using ProgressDialog, then Alejandro's approach works.  Use a view with some transparent background and show and hide as necessary. You will need to set clickable to true to capture clicks and thus prevent clickthrough though.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@color/some_kinda_dark_transparent_color"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: I'm not using ProgressDialog, i'm using ProgressBar... how to reach the same result?

Comment: I guess Alejandro's approach then.  Add a view with transparent src or background, and show and hide it as necessary.  You will need to set it to clickable in order for it to capture clicks and prevent click through though.  Its not elegant but it should work.
'   
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="some kinda transparent dark color"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:clickable="true"/>
'